# JQuery img src selector returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rss

I'm trying to retrieve RSS information with Google RSS API and AJAX. Most of the time it works fine, but I can seem to select an img withing a JQuery object for some reason. `$('img', content).attr('src')` returns `undefined`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/TM9Tx/)

```
var href = 'http://weheartit.com/pinterest.rss',
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=8&callback=?&q='+encodeURIComponent(href);

// Add ul tag to target element
$('#weheartit').append('<ul id="weheartit-feed-stream"></ul>');

// jQuery AJAX call
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: 'There is an AJAX error, revisit code.',
    success: function(a){
        a = a.responseData.feed.entries;
        $.each(a, function(i,item){
            if(i < 8){
                var content = $($.parseHTML(item.content));
                var thumb = $('img', content).attr('src');
                console.log(thumb);
                var html = '<li class="feed-image-wrapper"><a href="'+item.link+'" target="_blank"><div class="feed-image" style="background: url('+thumb+') no-repeat #dadada; background-size: cover;"></div></a></li>';
            }
            // Add WeHeartIt feed items to stream
            $('#weheartit-feed-stream').append(html);
        });
    },
    complete: function(a){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `content` itself is the image(value of content property is `<img alt="living life: one triiip at a time" src="http://data1.whicdn.com/images/40891301/large.jpg">`), so when you are using a context based search it looks for an descendant element which is not there.

You can use

```
var thumb = content.attr('src');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/usb57/)

Comment: That works perfectly! But what if `content` has more than 1 image in it http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/4nFa3/ ? It still works your way, but why?

Comment: because the image is the first element in `content`

Answer (score 1):

just change:

```
---
var thumb = $('img', content).attr('src');
---
```

to

```
...
// content is already a jQuery image object
var thumb = content.attr('src');
---
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TM9Tx/1/)